# informix trust local JDBC connections without password

Tags: jdbc, informix

When a user logs in to the (linux/unix) system as a user and runs a 4GL or ESQL/C program, the program can connect to a DB as the system account user without entering a password.  e.g. If I login as `rob` and run a program it can connect to a DB without providing a password, providing `rob` has connect permission.

I would like to do a similar thing with a local java program that uses JDBC to talk to the DB server.  Is this possible?

Comment: Just tried with jdbc from a local connection (no user or password on the jdbc url) and it connect without asking for authentication, just like 4GL and ESQL/C .

Comment: @LuísMarques You are right.  I tried this without setting the user and password in the connection and it works.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fully supported in the JDBC driver for Informix. You can connect without a password as the user who started the Java process that is on the same machine as the Informix server.

As Luis notes in his comment, you forego the username and password fields in your JDBC URL for this to work.